# vuforia unity pause tracking or augmentation

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have developed a 3d object detection AR app successfully. When a 3d object is shown, upon detecting,  the app shows some 3d Unity game objects which are hierarchal in vuforia object tracker . I want to give users an option in case if they don't have 3d object to detect, simply simulate as if object is detected and show the related 3d objects with the click of button.
could someone guide me please?

Answer (score 0):

why not you are using "User Defined Targets" with object detection

---

User-Defined Targets allow an end user to pick an image at runtime.      Thus, the user experiences AR “any time, anywhere” by selecting an       image – like a photograph, book cover or poster – from his or her       immediate environment without having to carry around pre-defined       targets.

simply download samples

1. Object Recog
2. User define target

from: https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples

and combine both